# Copiar un SpreadSheet con un formulario incluido

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

He creado un script para copiar una hoja de cálculo en una ubicación determinada.
El tema es que esta hoja tiene un formulario vinculado. Al hacer la copia se copia también el formulario nuevo.

Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de obtener la  Id del nuevo formulario que se ha creado para poder cambiarle el nombre.

Además sería ya lo máximo, si me podéis decir cómo se envía el enlace para que se pueda rellenar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
function COpiar_Pegar() {
  var PLANTILLA            = DocumentApp.openById("1BsmGqGpS7FmtU4En23dKaVhGDOcz1rCUeOJBIVhfuN4"); // PLANTILLA INFO BÁSICA EMPRESA
  var id_Carpeta_Empresas  = "1l_tRyaCD2GG6O0d_pDj9yab9fKF3NtE-"; //ID de carpetas
  var hojaControl          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      
 //Obtener Valores de la hoja control
    var UltimaFila                = hojaControl.getLastRow();
    var Razon_social              = hojaControl.getRange(UltimaFila,2).getValue();
    var EmailContacto             = hojaControl.getRange(UltimaFila,10).getValue();

    //CREAR CARPETA DE LA EMPRESA
    var CarpetaEmpresas                        = DriveApp.getFolderById("1l_tRyaCD2GG6O0d_pDj9yab9fKF3NEE");
    var NuevaCarpetaEmpresa                    = CarpetaEmpresas.createFolder(Razon_social);
    var Id_NuevaCarpetaEmpresa                      = NuevaCarpetaEmpresa.getId();

 //CREAR COPIA DE PLANTILLA
  var NuevaHojaEmpresa           = DriveApp.getFileById("1BsmGqGpS7FmtU4En23dKaVhGDOcz1rCUeOJBIVhfuN4").makeCopy(Razon_social, DriveApp.getFolderById(Id_NuevaCarpetaEmpresa)); 
  var Id_NuevaHojaEmpresa      = NuevaHojaEmpresa.getId();
  var URL_NuevaHojaEmpresa     = NuevaHojaEmpresa.getUrl();

  //CREAR COPIA DE PLANTILLA PARA RESPUESTAS EMPLEADOS
  var NuevaRespuestasEmpleados           = DriveApp.getFileById("1RKIjgSTZR70pYDgHOYDh6VohL5BDX-vCvSHC-ajXqJ0").makeCopy(Razon_social+ " Respuestas empleados", DriveApp.getFolderById(Id_NuevaCarpetaEmpresa)); 
  var Id_NuevaRespuestasEmpleados        = NuevaRespuestasEmpleados.getId();
  var URL_NuevaRespuestasEmpleados       = NuevaRespuestasEmpleados.getUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `getFormUrl()` con un objeto `Spreadsheet` o `Sheet`

Si lo usas con un objeto `Spreadsheet` y tu hoja de cálculo tiene más de un formulario, el formulario al que corresponderá el  URL es indeterminado (podría se cualquiera)

Si los usas con un objeto `Sheet` the devolverá el URL del formulario que envía datos a la hoja correspondiente o `null` si esa hoja no tiene ningún formulario asociado.

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getformurl
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getformurl